# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Here is my code:

```
int dim_y, dim_x;
int **map_boundaries;
int **map;

int main( int argc, char* args[] ){

    int i;

    scanf("%d",&dim_x);
    scanf("%d",&dim_y);

    map_boundaries = (int **)calloc(dim_y + 40,sizeof(int*)); 
    for(i = 0; i < dim_y + 40; i++){
         map_boundaries[i] = (int *)calloc(dim_x + 40,sizeof(int));
    }

    (*map)[dim_x+40] = (int(*)[dim_x+40])&map_boundaries[20][20];
}
```

The warning is for the last line, how should the last line be?

When I have it like this it works fine:

```
#define dim_y 500
#define dim_x 600

int map_boundaries[dim_y+40][dim_x+40];
int (*map)[dim_x+40] = (int(*)[dim_x+40])&map_boundaries[20][20];
```

But I want the values of "dim_x" and "dim_y" to be provided by the user and "map" to be global.

Comment: Actually what do you want to do in the last line...?

Comment: `map = map_boundaries;`

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR with the last line the map[0][0] points to map_boundaries[20][20], in fact map has negative index

Comment: You didn't even allocate `map`! You can assign `map_boundaries` to it like @BLUEPIXY but the variable doesn't make any sense. Currently you would write outside of array memory, if it weren't uninitialized...

Comment: just try this... `(**map) =map_boundaries[20][20];`

Comment: without allocating memory , how can we define boundary. i think , you may follow @BLUEPIXY 's point

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR i tried but nothing :/

Comment: This dereferences an uninitialized pointer

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to know what do you want to achieve. There is something obviously wrong with the last line, but without knowing your intent we will only guess how to fix it. Let's analyze your code.

1. Currently you are dereferencing (uninitialized) `(int**)` variable (`(int*)`) and then using it like array - this suggest that you intend `map` to be pointer to array of `int`s.
2. You are dynamically allocate 2-dimensional `map_boundaries` array with size of (`dim_x+40`) x (`dim_y+40`) - note that valid indexes will be respectively 0...`dim_x`+40-1 and 0...`dim_y`+40-1.

From your edit I understand that you want to use `map_boundaries` as helper to dynamically allocate global `map`.

Indeed you can allocate table like like you did. To assign whole array of `map_boundaries` to `map` you only need to do `map = map_boundaries;` like @BLUEPIXY suggested. Then You can make `map_boundaries` local.

```
int dim_y, dim_x;
int **map;

int main( int argc, char* args[] ){
    int **map_boundaries;

    scanf("%d",&dim_x);
    scanf("%d",&dim_y);

    map_boundaries = (int**) calloc(dim_y+40, sizeof(int*)); 
    for(int i = 0; i < dim_y+40; i++){
         map_boundaries[i] = (int*) calloc(dim_x+40, sizeof(int));
    }

    map = map_boundaries;
}
```

Warning occurs because:

1. `(*map)[dim_x+40]` is type of `int` (and you obtain it by dereferencing unallocated memory but compiler cannot know that).
2. `(int(*)[dim_x+40])` is (if I'm not mistaken) of type `array of pointers to int` (`(int*)[]`) - compiler implicitly cast it to `int` since you jest cast data into invalid type.

If that's not what you wanted to do, please elaborate on what you actually were trying to achieve, since it is not obvious.

EDIT:

Trimming `map_boundaries` to `map` (one way to do it):

```
int trimmed_dim_y_start = 0;
int trimmed_dim_y_size  = 20;
int trimmed_dim_x_start = 0;
int trimmed_dim_x_size  = 20;

// ...

map = (int**) calloc(trimmed_dim_y_size, sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < trimmed_dim_y_size; i++) {
    map[i] = map_boundaries[ trimmed_dim_y_start + i ] + trimmed_dim_x_start;
}
```

Note that in this variant you'll have to make `map_boundaries` global again since if you don't free all that calloc's you'll get memory leak. Maybe not so bad in this particular program but it's still an important practice to clean up things.

Comment: The way i have it the second code i posted, the map[0][0] is map_boundaries[20][20], the map[-1][0] is map_boundaries[19][20] and so on, i want to do this but i want the user to give the dim_x and dim_y

Comment: map = map_boundaries is correct, but map[0][0] is not map_boundaries[20][20] with this way

Comment: Do you want to perhaps trim `map_boundaries` or map it to `map`? If so then it cannot be done this way (with 1 assignment). You'll get that once you think about out what exactly `calloc` does and how arrays in C works.

Comment: yeah, when boundaries is a 2d array works fine but with calloc it doesn't allocate continuously the memory, i guess this is the fault. but how could i do this?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to do it manually - I edited answer to add an example how to do it. I weren't sure if you wanted to trim it to 20x20 or make it start at 20x20 so feel free to change that part.

Answer (score -2):

Remove bracket from int(*) and place all int* in brackets.

```
(*map)[dim_x+40] = ((int*)[dim_x+40])&map_boundaries[20][20];
```

Comment: error: expected expression before ‘[’ token
      (* map)[dim_x+40] = ((int*)[dim_x+40])&map_boundaries[20][20];

Comment: (int(\*)[dim_x+40]) are you shoure that this is right expression? Index of what are you tried to get? Of int(\*). In fact, my compiler even doesn't want compile it.

Comment: Yes i took the code from the second post from here  http://everything2.com/title/Negative+array+indexing. If you do it the way i post in the second part it will work